# sending js value as parameter to js function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440154/sending-value-from-one-js-function-to-another-as-parameter) and answer is correct but I'm was not perfectly clear. On the init page load everything is ok, but I need to call with date parameter as argument.

So this is fine

```
$('#myDate').click(function () { 
     var date = getDate();
  })
```

but I should send this date to

```
 $('#dataTable').dataTable({
...
```

**Update**

`Ok, I'm simplifying this,`

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable({    
...
```

on page load takes myDate value and sends this value to the controller. This is fine. Problem is when after page load user pick some other date, I want again to send this data value to the  `$('#dataTable').dataTable({..`

Hope this helps, thanks

```
        function getDate() {
            var date = $('input[name="myDate"]').val();
            return date;
        };

        $('#myDate').click(function () {
            var date = getDate();            
            return date;
        });

        $('#dataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Home/Ajax",
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                var date = getDate();
                aoData.push({ "name": "myDate", "value": date });
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
function getDate() {
    var date = $('input[name="myDate"]').val();
    return date;
}

$('#myDate').click(updateDate);

function updateDate() { 
    $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Home/Ajax",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            var date = getDate();
            aoData.push({ "name": "myDate", "value": date });
        },
        //... I assume there's more
}

updateDate();
```